# Using react bootstrap carousal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use React carousel component given in below tutorial:

[react-bootstrap-carousel](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/carousel/)

In the post I see the images are loaded from path:

```
<img
className="d-block w-100"
src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
alt="Third slide"
/>
```

What is `holder.js` here, the tutorial did not mention what this javascript contains. Also, the image should have extension as jpg or png etc instead of js, so the tutorial says they have image `holder.js`?

Can you please help me in understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`holder.js`](http://holderjs.com/) is a client-side placeholder image generator.

It's not required for the carousel to work, it simply generates the images that the carousel displays. This is so they can have a nice demo without having to manually make/find a bunch of images.

`src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"` is telling the img element to load up an image from the image generator.

`800x400` is the size of the generated image.
`Second slide` is the text to put in the generated image.
`282c34` is the background colour of the generated image.

You should set the `src` to be the URL to whatever image you want to show.

e.g.

`src="MyContentDirectory/MyImage.jpg"`
`src="MyImageApi/GetImage/MyImage.jpg"`
`src="https://example.com/somethirdpartysiteimage.jpg"`